# equivalent of ASP.NET MVC TempData in ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net, tempdata

In ASP.NET MVC, there's a TempData which can pass data one time from one page to another.  What's the equivalent for this in ASP.NET?

Comment: Session and Viewstate bai Rob :D

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is no direct equivalent (that is, data that is only passed to the next page).

You can use `Session` and clear it out on the receiving page.

Answer (score -2):

You can use either Session or [Viewstate](http://codeproject.com/KB/viewstate/AccessViewState.aspx) to pass data between pages in ASP.NET application.

Comment: `ViewState` between pages? I don't think so.

Comment: I suggest you read the article. He is using [`Server.Transfer`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms525800.aspx). This is not the same a loading a new page or doing a redirect.

Comment: Oded, will it do what @rob waminal asks for or not. I'm not discussing about Responce.Redirect versus Server.Transfer when in this case you right they are different.

Comment: @eugeneK: I'll be passing some query strings to the called page so Server.Transfer is a no.

Comment: Then you can save in Cache and Application but this will be global to all application users, so use Session for user specific data.