# Post/Redirect/Get with alert to user?

Tags: javascript, asp.net, post-redirect-get

I have an ASP.NET WebForms application that process a post request and displays a message to the user via JavaScript alert (via `ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript`...). At some point after that client-side code executes that refreshes the page and of course I am getting *"To display this page, Firefox must send information that will repeat any action (such as a search or order confirmation) that was performed earlier"* or similar ones in other browsers.

Now, I know about [Post/Redirect/Get](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Post/Redirect/Get) pattern, but if I do redirect right after the post - I cannot display the JS alert. Is there a way to display alert and execute server-side redirect? I know I can add a specific querystring to redirect URL, check it on page load and display the alert if it's present, but that means if redirected page is refreshed - I will get that alert again, which is undesirable. Is there a way to do that that wouldn't involve complicated messy flags?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`TempData` in ASP.NET MVC is intended for redirects. If you store a message there you will be able to check for it and display it following a redirect. If the page is refreshed the value will not be persisted though, so won't be visible a second time, complementing the PRG pattern.

I've seen it implemented as an extension for ActionResults, like in the FunnelWeb weblog source:

https://github.com/funnelweblog/FunnelWeb/blob/f28d1b1cb9c86e492f120948309de68c12141222/src/FunnelWeb.Web/Application/Mvc/MvcExtensions.cs

For WebForms, I believe the only option is to use `Session` and clear it after access, although you should be able to create a wrapper around it, like in the link above, which functions in the same way:

[equivalent of ASP.NET MVC TempData in ASP.NET](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6198037/equivalent-of-asp-net-mvc-tempdata-in-asp-net)

Comment: I don't think TempData is available in a WebForms application. Unless I am mistaken?

Comment: Apologies - missed that. I think Session is the only option! I've added a bit to my answer.

Comment: Thank you. I usually try to avoid Session for these kinds of scenarios, but it does seem like the only feasible solution.

Comment: Hide it in a class to make yourself feel better - that's what I always do.